# regex - finding multiple occurances of a pattern and extracting a string

Tags: php, regex, string, extract, preg-match-all

i have a code

```
<?php
$string='afdsfd data-win="3453453ASSS" some text data-win="3434534ASDDD" some more text data-win="1233RTYYY"';
preg_match_all('/data-win="([^"]+)"/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

this is the output i get

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => data-win="3453453ASSS"
            [1] => data-win="3434534ASDDD"
            [2] => data-win="1233RTYYY"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3453453ASSS
            [1] => 3434534ASDDD
            [2] => 1233RTYYY
        )

)
```

what am, i doing wrong ? All i wanted was Array[1] and not Array[0]

Comment: `$matches[0]`. Or `'/data-win="\K[^"]+/'`

Comment: I don't think you're doing anything wrong. 
When back references are involved they usually always start with \\1 or $1 when it's related to anything you put inside brackets as a specific capture.

If you never used your brackets, the assumption is that the return would always be at [0]. All that's happening is that you are still getting your [0] but anything after that is being stored as 1,2,3,4 depending on how many brackets() you used to capture other segments.

I might be wrong but that has always been my understanding :)

Comment: Wiktors code worked.